# Hive partition pruning on computed column

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, emr

I have a few tables on Hive and my query is trying to retrieve the data for the past x days. Hive is pruning the partitions when I use a direct date, but is doing a full table scan when using a formula instead.

```
select *
from   f_event
where  date_key > 20160101;

scanned partitions..

s3://...key=20160102 [f]
s3://...key=20160103 [f]
s3://...key=20160104 [f]
```

If I use a formula, say, to get the past 4 weeks of data

```
Select count(*)
From    f_event f
Where  date_key  > from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()-2*7*60*60*24, 'yyyyMMdd')
```

**This is scanning all partitions in the table.**

environment : Hadoop 2.6.0, EMR, Hive on S3, Hive 1.0.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hive doesn't trigger partition pruning when the filtering expression contains non-deterministic functions such as `unix_timestamp()`.

A good reason for this was mentioned in [the discussion](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.hadoop.hive.user/3673):

> Imagine a situation where you had:
>
> `WHERE partition_column = f(unix_timestamp()) AND ordinary_column =
>   f(unix_timestamp)`.
>
> The right hand side of the predicate has to be evaluated at map-time,
>   whereas you're assuming that left hand side should be evaluated at
>   compile time, which means you have two different values of
>   unix_timestamp() floating around, which can only end badly.